# Remove Spaces From Entire Column VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to remove spaces from all the text values within column B, starting at row B2. Here is a piece of code that works by removing the spaces, line by line, through column B:

```
Sub RemoveSpacing()

    Set AssetToolSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AssetName Sheet")
    Dim startingLine As Double
    startingLine = 2
    
    With AssetToolSheet
        Do While .Cells(startingLine, 2) <> ""
            .Cells(startingLine3, 2).Replace " ", ""
            startingLine = startingLine + 1
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

Would like to reference an entire range (for example, B2:B) and remove spaces all at once, rather than line by line.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not Edit : Replace ? replace " " with "".

Comment: Thanks @SolarMike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could start below code which will replaces all spaces in A column without looping through each cell.

```
Sub Macro1()
' replace spaces with ''
    Columns("A:A").Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows
End Sub
```

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks Sathish!